# ruby each loop in order on sql order query result

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a query in my Controller that works perfectly:

> @klasses_mon = Klass.order(:start).where(day: 'MON').find_each

my result is (shown by `<%= @klasses_mon.inspect %>` in my view):

```
#<Enumerator: #<ActiveRecord::Relation 
[#<Klass id: 9, name: "Cycling", teacher: "Tomek", day: "MON", start: 510, duration: 45>,
#<Klass id: 8, name: "LBT", teacher: "Monia", day: "MON", start: 600, duration: 60>, 
#<Klass id: 11, name: "HIIT", teacher: "Aga", day: "MON", start: 930, duration: 45>]>
:find_each({:start=>nil, :finish=>nil, :batch_size=>1000, :error_on_ignore=>nil})>
```

But I am trying to display it in each loop. For some reason it is not ordered anymore. Looks like each loop does not keep the order from my query result:

```
<% @klasses_mon.each do |k| %>
    <p><%= k.teacher %>,
    <%= k.name %>
    START: <%= k.start/60 %>:<%= k.start%60 %>
<% end %>
```

result:

> Monia, LBT START: 10:0
>
> Tomek, Cycling START: 8:30
>
> Aga, HIIT START: 15:30

How should I do that?

Comment: @muistooshort integer

Comment: Why are you using `#find_each`? Are you loading thousands of records here?

Comment: @DRSE I don't know how many records I will have, but not thousands... That's what I found while looking for a way to query all MON klass but order them by start value... I guess mistake than? What is alternative? EDIT: found it: find_all would be better?

Comment: Please see my answer.  You shouldn't need `#find_all` or `#all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each):

> **find_each**(start: nil, finish: nil, batch_size: 1000, error_on_ignore: nil)
>   [...]
>   NOTE: It's not possible to set the order. That is automatically set to ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering work. This also means that this method only works when the primary key is orderable (e.g. an integer or string).

So `find_each` is explicitly documented to ignore any ordering that you try to use.

`find_each` doesn't use LIMIT and OFFSET to move the batch window through the result set as that tends to be very expensive as the OFFSET increases, instead it orders by the primary key and includes a `id > last_one` condition in the WHERE clause to set the start of the batch and a LIMIT clause to set the batch size. Ordering by the PK and querying on the PK are both generally inexpensive as is a LIMIT clause.

`find_each` is the wrong tool for this job, `find_each` is for batch work but you're just displaying a short list of records so you want a simple:

```
@klasses_mon = Klass.order(:start).where(day: 'MON')
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `#find_each` ignores any scoped `order` and forces a sort by the primary key (usually `id`).  This is stated in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) and is because `#find_each` needs to make sure that it doesn't repeat any records during iteration.

You can see this in your console if you try:

```
> @klasses_mon = Klass.order(:start).where(day: 'MON').find_each
> @klasses_mon.map(&:start) # force the relation to execute and return rows.
Scoped order is ignored, it's forced to be batch order.
Klass Load (0.ms) SELECT "klasses".* FROM "klasses" WHERE "klasses"."day" = 'MON' ORDER BY "klasses"."id"
=> [600, 510, 930]
```

If you're not expecting to run through thousands of rows, you can drop the `find_each`:

```
@klasses_mon = Klass.where(day: "MON").order(:start)
```

Comment: I think it is more of an efficiency issue than a consistency issue, the docs even say "NOTE: By its nature, batch processing is subject to race conditions if other processes are modifying the database". But yeah, `find_each` isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: Yup, understood and agreed.  I normally think efficiency because the method is specifically intended to prevent instantiating huge sets of objects at once.  Instead, creating a thousand or so at a time so they can be GCed as the loop progresses and they aren't need any more.  The doc for `find_each` says as much, right at the beginning: "Looping through a collection of records from the database (using the ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named::ClassMethods#all method, for example) is very inefficient since it will try to instantiate all the objects at once."